# How can I get first n bits of floating point number as integer in python

Tags: python, floating-point, bit

Suppose I have `0.625` as a floating point is `0b.101`, so if I want the first two bits of that as an integer i.e. `0b10` = `2`, how can I achieve this in python?

I've tried taking the number to a power of 2 and casting to an int, so if I want `n` bits I do `int(0.625*(2**n))`. But that is not working for me.

The problem occurs when I have a number greater than `1` so `24.548838022726972` will give me `392` rather than `12` for the first four bits. (`24.548838022726972` = `0b11000.100011001...`)

Comment: The following example code you provide , outputs `2` for me , what's problem with yours?

Comment: @Arman Edited, sorry, I didn't at first include the real issue

Comment: why first two bit for 0.625 ant first four for 24.5488... ?

Comment: @B.M. Just for examples, I want to be able to do this with any number of bits

Comment: You can use `math.frexp` to normalise your number so that it lies between `0.5` and `1.0`. For example: `int(math.frexp(24.54883)[0] * 2**4)` gives your the first four bits of `24.54883`.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Thanks! This worked, if you make this an answer I will accept it, I didn't know about math.frexp to give me the significand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the `n` most significant bits, one way to start is to use [`math.frexp`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.frexp) to normalise your number to lie in the range `[0.5, 1.0)`. Then multiplying by `2**n` and taking the integer part will give you what you need.

```
>>> import math
>>> math.frexp(24.54883)  # significand and exponent
(0.7671509375, 5)
>>> math.frexp(24.54883)[0]  # just the significand
0.7671509375
>>> int(math.frexp(24.54883)[0] * 2**4)  # most significant 4 bits
12
```

Instead of explicitly computing a power of `2` to scale by, you could use the [`math.ldexp`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.ldexp) function to do the second part of the operation.

```
>>> int(math.ldexp(math.frexp(24.54883)[0], 4))
12
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`struct.pack()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) to convert a floating point number to a list of bytes, and then extract the bits you're interested in from there.

Answer (score 0):

```
While the number is greater than or equal to 1, divide by 2.
Multiply by 2**n
Round or truncate to an integer.
```

Here is a simplified Java program for the test case:

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    double in = 24.548838022726972;
    while (in >= 1) {
      in /= 2;
      System.out.println(in);
    }
    in *= 16;
    System.out.println(in);
    System.out.println((int) in);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
12.274419011363486
6.137209505681743
3.0686047528408715
1.5343023764204358
0.7671511882102179
12.274419011363486
12
```

Answer (score 0):

A direct way to obtain the significant bits of the mantissa in the [IEEE 754 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) with builtin functions is:

```
In [2]: u=24.54883

In [3]: bin(u.as_integer_ratio()[0])
Out[3]: '0b11000100011001000000000011111011101010001000001001101'

In [4]: u=.625

In [5]: bin(u.as_integer_ratio()[0])
Out[5]: '0b101'
```

You obtain   `0b1` + mantissa without non significant 0.

Comment: The `as_integer_ratio` method always reduces to lowest terms, so the numerator could have anything from `1` bit to `53` bits. (i.e., `len(bits)` could be anything between `3` and `55`).